# maps as anonymous struct members

Tags: dictionary, go

I was stumbling over some behavior in go which I cannot make sense of completely and explainations of any kind would be wellcome:

```
type Test struct{
    Name string // or other metadata to be stored along the core map element
    map[string]string
}
```

The above code will fail to compile with an `unexpected map` error.
Which is probably because struct Field delarations must be types, however I fail to appriciate why `map[string]string` is not a type.

Changing it to

```
type Embedded map[string]string

type Test struct{
    Name string
    Embedded
}
```

get's arround the compiler error, but still `Test["someKey"]` raises the compiler error
`invalid operation: Test["someKey"] (index of type Test)`.

Of course adressing the anoymous field directly with Test.Embedded["someKey"] works,
but my questions are:

- Why are literal map declarations valid as types in non-anonymous field declarations but not valid in anonymous fields
- Why does indexing the containing type not work? Why can't it work?

Thanks for clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Anonymous fields](http://golang.org/ref/spec#AnonymousField) must be named types only. You're perhaps somewhat confusing [Type](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type), [LiteralType](http://golang.org/ref/spec#LiteralType) and [TypeName](http://golang.org/ref/spec#TypeName).
2. Referring to an anonymous field is presribed by the specs to be done always by its type name. Thus `Test.Embedded[key]` is the only legal form. Here you might be confusing the embedded field *methods*,  which are inherited from embedded fields w/o need to use the field name and the field *value*, which must use it.

Comment: So why isn't the "[]" operation an inherited method?

Comment: @joshlf13 B/c operators are not methods.

Comment: heh I figured that might be the answer.